# Help with NPN and PNP common emitter

Tags: transistors, analog, bjt

I have a circuit that has the emitter side of a NPN tied to the emitter side of PNP. I need to find the output voltage on the emitter. Base voltage is a sine wave. Can someone help me understand what this kind of configuration is used for? And how should I go about to calculate the power dissipated by the resistor?

[image]

Comment: you're going to have to at least draw a schematic and give transistor numbers...

Comment: Sorry I didn't upload a schematic at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

This is a push-pull emitter follower. 
The ideal case: the output equals the input.
The practical case: there is a Vbe (~0.7V) crossover distortion which causes a deadband for input signals around 0V.

Comment: Perfect. This definitely helps