# Amplifier Biasing

Tags: bjt, bias

So I have amplifier circuit that is biased using a sine wave and a DC offset on the NPN and PNP [see this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86646/11861). Wouldn't biasing the circuit at 1v short out the circuit as VBE~07V?

Here is a copy of the schematic:
[image]

Comment: You had cleaned up you previous question nicely, then you edited it and re-asked it here.  It would have been better to continue to refine your other question rather than to gut it.

Comment: Or you could have edited this question to more accurately reflect a refinement of your learning questing.

Answer (score 0):

In this circuit, with the sine wave generator at 0 volts, both transistors are on due to the 0.8 volt sources connected to their bases. The output is also sitting at 0 volts due to the symmetry of the circuit.  As the sine wave rises above 0 volts the NPN transistor turns on harder since its base emitter voltage is increasing. Thus the sine wave voltage will appear at the output across R1.  When the sine wave starts to fall below 0 volts, the PNP transistor turns on harder since its base emitter voltage is now decreasing.  Again, this will cause the sine wave voltage to appear at the output.  The 0.8 volt sources, V1 and V2, serve to avoid having the sine wave not appear at the output until its level goes above +0.8 volts or below -0.8 volts. If these sources were not present, the output sine wave would exhibit what is known as cross-over distortion, where the portion of the sine wave near its zero crossings is missing from the output because the transistors do not turn on until their base emitter voltages reach about 0.7 volts (for silicon transistors). In a real circuit, V1 and V2 would be replaced by diodes fed by resistors from the main power supplies, V5 and V7.

Comment: Thanks Barry, but doesn't KVL have to hold true? if the supplies are 0.8V and Vbe =0.7V KVL doesn't work?

Comment: Vbe is not a battery and its voltage will vary with the current through the transistor since there is a resistance associated with the base-emitter junction.  If you impress 0.8 volts across the base-emitter the base current will be whatever it has to be for that particular transistor's emitter-base characteristic.  It is nominally 0.7 volts for a wide range of current but this is only an approximation.  In real circuits, the base voltage is not supplied by a battery but a source (like a diode) which also has internal resistance so the base-emitter voltage of the transistor will adjust itself.

Answer (score 0):

The forward voltage characteristic of a BJT's base emitter junction has to be taken into account - it is basically a diode and it doesn't draw infinite current as the voltage hits 0.700001V: -

[image]

You bias the base with a voltage that causes a certain amount of current to pass through to collector to the emitter and this may require 0.5V or a little higher (say 0.7V). Some power amplifiers may well need more than 0.7V and have a collector current (when no signal is present) of an amp. This is just to try and avoid cross-over distortion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical issue with what is known as a class A amplifier.  You trade off efficiency for linearity and you also limit power.  This is all because you run power through the limb from rail to rail that does not get put into the load.  The current handling capacity of the transistors are in effect wasted (but that depends upon you view point).  So yes, it does sort of short your rails, but it helps to minimize other effects like cross over distortion.